# What are the Implications of Passwordless SSH

Tags: ssh, password

If UNIX users reach  servers via SSH, and we only want to allow pubkey logins, are there any other items that need to be added to this list, that I should be concerned with?

1. Allow `pubkey login` in the `sshd_config` file on the server.
2. Considerations for a Default password, such as **"!"** or **"*"**

Comment: You forgot to mention: which Unix systems (yes, even give a set if this is not just Linux, for example) and which SSH server implementations. There are plenty of both and when combined this creates quite a heap of possible setups.

Comment: you should tell the `sshd` to not allow password authentication. The user can still have a password, it will be needed for `sudo` and maybe other sub-systems.

Answer (score 8):

It would have been good to tell what SSH server you ask for and what (set of) Unix systems.

`!` and `*` are not passwords when you see them in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow` (use `getent` to read those entries).

They are markers that denote whether the account has a password or not and whether it is locked or not.

This is an important distinction, depending on the configuration and version of PAM and the distribution, *if you're on Linux*. If locked, it's less likely you will be permitted to log in, but on the other hand it is possible that it works out of the box on older systems (at least that's my experience).

You can use (as superuser) `passwd -l <name>` to lock an account (`!`) or `passwd -d <name>` to delete the password from it (`*`) and you can also combine both, which would simply ensure that any existing password gets removed: `passwd -dl <name>`.

You don't say, but assuming OpenSSH the relevant directives in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (path may vary) are:

```
HostKey ...
```

The server has to have a host key or either RSA2 or DSA (and more modern implementation add two elliptic curve implementations, too). RSA1 has long been abandoned by all common SSH server implementations.

Then:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
```

I would also always recommend to set up `/etc/sudoers` and completely disallow `root` login via SSH (`PermitRootLogin no`). However, there can be a minor disadvantage to this more secure setup, when the disk is full and your unprivileged `sudo` member doesn't get to write to the disk, but `root` would (due to the reserved space). So YMMV.

### Two more pieces of advice

#### Assign a group to limit SSH access

Create a group `ssh-users` (or whatever name you please) and set the respective directive in `sshd_config`. Make sure that `root` is or isn't member of that group according to the policy you chose based on the information above.

```
AllowGroups ssh-users
```

#### Assign a group to confine users to *only* SFTP access

In `sshd_config` the following will then make sure users cannot escape `/home` and certain functionality is disabled for them.

```
Match group sftponly
    ChrootDirectory /home
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

### Conclusion

So yes, PAM would have to be added as a consideration if on Linux.

Also whether to allow agent forwarding or leave that to you users.

And last but not least whether to allow them to forward ports or X11 connections. Especially ports can be undesirable, as they allow a user to use your server as a proxy.

The `Match` directive lets you also limit users with respect to from where they are connecting (a firewall can also do that or the TCP wrappers).

Do you want your users to be allowed to manage the keys or do you want to abstract that and make the direct access to `authorized_keys` unavailable to them?

There are certainly more aspects, but they are mostly at a more fine-grained level of detail and as such variations of the aforementioned points.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the user wants it to be, considering any policies on password complexity. If the only access is via SSH and `PasswordAuthentication` is `no` in [`sshd_config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sshd_config.5), then it does not matter what the password is. Also note that entries in [`shadow`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/shadow.5) are encrypted passwords, so the values of `!` and `*` are not *passwords* - but strings which are not valid encrypted values, thus preventing password-based login.

Comment: doesn't the "!" lock the user, so he will not be able to use cron?

Comment: @freaking-good-question No, password locking has no relation to `cron` as far as I can tell.

Comment: @muru: wrong, this would depend on your authentication mechanism. On Linux this would involve PAM and that may indeed have a different configuration depending on the distro and the customizations. So yeah, this subtle difference matters. It just depends how much it matters on your system.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I am not sure which part you're saying "wrong" to, and your answer fails to make it clear.

Comment: @muru: "wrong" was aimed at your comment above. `cron` and locking of accounts may very well be related. I pointed out in my comment what the relation is. If you have more questions, feel free to ask it and point me (from here) to your question.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I wondered if it was about `cron`, or the answer. Can you show an instance of `cron` being affected by a locked account?

Comment: Space is too limited in a comment. PAM *is* the connection, though. You might want to read up on the topic (`man pam.d`, `man pam.conf`, `man pam`). The trick is basically that on most systems the default for `cron` and friends will be to use a PAM config for noninteractive sessions and everything else for interactive sessions. You never know what the PAM configuration contains (e.g. on Solaris `pam_unix_account` *does* check for locked accounts by default) - PAM has been adopted by other Unix systems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19996/discussion-between-0xc0000022l-and-muru).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but there is an opportunity to change the password by running up a new password file in `/etc/passwd`. If not, try the probably more effective by less stable option of messing around with `sshd_config`, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you now what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running something similar to RHEL/CentOS w/ OpenSSH, these are the things I typically do when going passwordless:

- Configure sshd_config to only accept pubkey authentication (`PubkeyAuthentication yes,
  PasswordAuthentication no, ChallengeResponseAuthentication no, UsePAM no`)
- Set all existing users to have a non-valid password (`chpasswd -e 'pubkey!!' <username>`)
- Remove password expiration from all existing users (`chage -M -1 <username>`)
- If using sudo, ensure all user specifications are marked NOPASSWD (e.g. `%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`)
- Ensure your user creation process will maintain these requirements (e.g. `useradd -p 'pubkey!!' -K MAX_PASS_DAYS=-1 <username>`)

Before locking out password access, make doubly sure you're able successfully authenticate via pubkey.  Ensure your /home partition isn't on a network mount (or anything else that might not always be available).  There are few things worse than losing access to your server because it can't get to your pubkey.  If the system is headless, make sure you have some way to quickly get direct console access in case of emergency (KVM, virtual console, crash cart, etc.).

That all being said, I would consider putting a password on the account of anyone with full sudo access, and configure sudoers to require a password from them.  If everything else is configured as above, they still won't be able to log into the server with this password, but it will give you a little extra protection against someone sitting down at their command prompt and doing "bad things(tm)".

Answer (score 0):

Another important consideration is password expiration.  Just because SSH is set to enforce passwordless authentication does not mean that the login process will ignore passwords if told to check expiration.

This is extremely important because there is not way to SSH into a server with a user account that has an expired password (from my own experience).

Password expiration can be defined or set in a number of places, including passwd file, login.defs file, the relevant pam authorization file, as well as other places (e.g. database).  It is important to check what the password policy is on your system and your organization.

A couple of ways around this might be to 1) allow passwords for certain users in the sshd_config and/or 2) attempt to have certain users that do not have their passwords expire.  This second option is not likely possible in environments where passwords are set to expire from a global configuration, like login.defs and pam auth files.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a UNIX (HP UX) machine and not Linux then you will need to add `rcommand` to your pam.conf under the sshd account.

```
sshd     account sufficient /usr/lib/security/libpam_ldap.1 rcommand
```

Otherwise you will get a password prompt that won't take when trying to ssh into the machine.